# Parse XML file in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, parsexml

I am trying to retrieve Exchange Rates from Yahoo

```
$browser = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$browser.Proxy.Credentials =[System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials 

$url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote'
$xml = New-Object xml
$xml.Load($url)

[xml]$YahooDataDocument = $xml.InnerXml
$YahooDataDocument.List.resources.resource | format-table name,price
```

But I am unable to get the data as required, I only get:

```
Name     price
----     -----
resource      
resource      
resource      
resource      
resource      
.
.
..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$browser = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$browser.Proxy.Credentials =[System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials 
$url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote'
[xml]$xml = $browser.DownloadString($url)

$resultset = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach ($quote in $xml.list.resources.resource){
    $singlequote = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary
    foreach($element in $quote.field){
        $singlequote.Add($element.name,$element.'#text')
    }
    $resultset += New-Object PSObject -Property $singlequote
}
$resultset | format-table
```

Thing is when you are getting **$xml.list.resources.resource** it comes as **System.Array** so you need to deal with every object separately.